# Drools 6 loading and executing rule from String

Tags: drools

I am trying to load a rule from a String in Drools 6 like this:

```
// the rule
def drl = '''
dialect "mvel"

rule "Person is over 18"
    when
        $person : Person(age > 18)
    then
        System.out.println("Person is "+$person.name);
end
'''
// setup for rule
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get()
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem()
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.drl",
    kieServices.getResources().newReaderResource( new StringReader(drl) ) )
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll()

// check there have been no errors for rule setup
Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
    println( results.getMessages() )
    throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" )
}
KieContainer kieContainer =
    kieServices.newKieContainer( kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId() )
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession()

// insert facts and fire rules
kieSession.insert(new Person("Jon Doe", 21))
kieSession.insert(new Person("Jon Darcy", 1))
kieSession.fireAllRules()

kieSession.dispose()

@Immutable
class Person {
    String name
    int age
}
```

What I wanted to happen is getting the person name printed out. By attaching eventlistener and logger I can see that the facts are added and asserted. By having an error in the drl I can be sure the rule is seen and compiled. But the rule never fires.

I am pretty sure there is jsut a stupid little mistake somewhere in the code. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting a KieBase from the KieContainer and creating the KieSession from that is what works for me:

```
KieContainer kieContainer =
   kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId() );
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
```

But your code is working, too - at least after doing it all in Java, and making sure that Person and the DRL file are in the same package.

```
String drl = "package drlstring;\n" +
    "dialect 'mvel'\n" +
    "rule Person_is_over_18\n" +
    "when\n" +
    "$person : Person(age > 18)\n" +
    "then\n" +
    "System.out.println(\"Person is \"+$person.getName());\n" +
    "end";
// setup for rule
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.drl",
       kieServices.getResources().newReaderResource( new StringReader(drl) ) );
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();

// check there have been no errors for rule setup
Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
if( results.hasMessages( Message.Level.ERROR ) ){
    System.out.println( results.getMessages() );
    throw new IllegalStateException( "### errors ###" );
}
KieContainer kieContainer =
    kieServices.newKieContainer( kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId() );
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();

// insert facts and fire rules
kieSession.insert(new Person("Jon Doe", 21));
kieSession.insert(new Person("Jon Darcy", 1));
kieSession.fireAllRules();
kieSession.dispose();
```

If you want to continue with your Scala setup, narrow the possible causes for the failure to fire down by adding a rule with an empty condition:

```
rule hello
when then 
  System.out.println( "Hello!" );
end
```

I *think* it is the Scala definition of class Person that isn't recognized by the Drools engine.

Comment: you mean my code worked with your change? Because here it seems not to be the case

Comment: It seems that there is some other reason for the rule not firing. See my extended answer.

Comment: It seems the problem is not the language the controlling code was written in (which is btw Groovy not Scala). I was able to use your empty condition rule to get the confirmation for it working. The problem seems to be that Person is not recognized by the Drools engine. Do you know why? It is an almost normal java class in the end after all. And afaik it worked in Drools 5.5. Are there constraints I am not aware of? Is there documentation that could explain me why?

Comment: As you have seen from my answer, I have no experience with those new languages. It is possible that the @Immutable throws a spanner into the works. - Using Drools with anything else but Java hasn't been guaranteed yet by the Drools team, AFAIK.